# Scoping the Screen Size -- Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, scope, screen-size

The answer to this question may be too advanced for me, but I would still like to give it a try.  I am able to determine and set the value for the screen size within a method, but it does not have scope outside of that method.  My question is, how do I give it scope inside the entire class?  Also inside the entire project?  Thanks.  Here is what I am using to determine the screen size, but it only works inside a single method:

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

---

Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you just declare `int width` and `int height` outside of your method and then assign them values inside your method?

Comment: my goal is just to declare the variables one time, then never worry about it again

Comment: oh i see what your saying. i guess that should work. i shouldve thought of that on my own. thanks! make that an answer so i can checkmark you please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, how do I give it scope inside the entire class? Also inside the entire project?

If you only want to worry about setting those values once, extending the `Application` class would probably be a good start.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private Point mDimensions;

    @Override public void onCreate() {
        // this will only get run on app startup
        DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        mDimensions = new Point(width, height);
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return mDimensions.x;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return mDimensions.y;
    }
}
```

To access the getter methods, set the `android:name` attribute on the application tag in your project's manifest:

```
<application android:name="com.myname.MyApplication" ... ></application>
```

You can then cast the result of any `getApplication()` and `getApplicationContext()` call to `MyApplication` and call the methods; e.g.

```
int width = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getWidth();
```

Do note that since the width and height values are initialized only once, they will **not** change on screen orientation changes. If you want to take that into account too, a simple util method accepting a context instance (can be e.g. an `Activity` or `Service`) is probably a more straightforward solution.

```
public static Point getDimensions(Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    return new Point(width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And return the result with the method, you can make the method to be public, or use any getter method.

Answer (score 0):

In your method declare `int width` and `int height`, and then change them as nessecary. To access them from a deferent method, just declare them as public, like `public int width`

Or if you what to make them private, then you can use a getter and setter method.